# How do i make a range slider touch screen friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a small project and i need to change the animation duration of an element with a range slider.It works in desktop but not in mobile screen

```js
let range1 = document.getElementById("Range");
let line = document.getElementById("radarLine");

function setSpeed() {
  line.style.animationDuration = range1.value + 's';
}

range1.addEventListener("mousemove", setSpeed);
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min=".005" max="20" value="4" id="Range" step=".05">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mousemove`, try `touchmove`

Comment: Try to detect if you are on a device or not

Comment: I am.maybe I should add another event listener for touchmove seperately?